# Flask Blueprint self redirect

Tags: python, flask

I keek getting an error:

werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'foo.bar,  id=1'. Did you mean 'foo.bar' instead?

```
foobp= Blueprint('foo', __name__)

@foobp.route('/bar/<id>', , methods=['get', 'post'])
def bar(id):
    id_var = id
    form = SomeForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # do database stuff
        return redirect(url_for('foo.bar, id={}'.format(id_var)))
    # do some other stuff
    return render_template('bar'html, form=form, ...)
```

I have tried dropping the `'foo.bar'` and doing just `'bar'` but that doesn't seem to work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also tried a relative redirect `'.bar'`

Comment: its `return redirect(url_for('.bar', id=id))`, used to doing url_for in the html templates not the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return redirect(url_for('foo.bar', id=id_var))
```

Also you have two commas in your route definition.

Comment: Yes, the two commas was a type! Sorry about that.